# Use USB interface to paste wifi password

Tags: windows-vista, printer

I've just purchased an Epson XP-315 wifi printer. I've connected it to a Windows Vista PC with USB (so far so good) but I'd also like to connect the printer to my home wifi network. However, I can't find any tool, wizard or control panel that allows to configure wifi from my PC. Apparently, I'm supposed to type the 63-character wifi password using the printer front panel.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Usually you can configure the wifi part using the printer CD whilst it is connected via USB... run the CD and see what the software let's you do... Your wifi key is seriously 63 characters long? You could change your key to minimum 8 characters but just so long as it is WPA2 encryption and sufficiently complex passphrase you should be fine for home use...

Comment: When I select "configure wifi" in the CD wizard it just freezes while (apparently) looking for an already configured printer. My key is actually 60 characters long—I've never had to *type* it it in seven years. Trying to change it right now, but router claims my network will be slower... :-!

Comment: The configure wifi part is going to look for a printer already connected to your wifi (which yours isn't)... ok. I think you're going to need to give it your key using the printer panel... a pain, yes, but once it's done, it's done... a 60 character WPA2 key is a bit overkill for a home config...

Comment: I've finally taken the path of least resistance and reconfigured wifi on all other devices. I've switched to Epson from HP but I guess printer software is crap no matter the vendor. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Álvaro-g-vicario: please consider deleting or closing your question and/or provide an accepted answer yourself.